# int level is not showing in the SMS

Tags: java, android

am creating a project that sends the vale of battery by sms when the activity is oepend,but the sms is received with value 0 and not the batter percentage can u help

```
  private void getBatteryPercentage() {
        BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                context.unregisterReceiver(this);
               currentLevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
               final int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
                level = -1;
                if (currentLevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
                    level = (currentLevel * 100) / scale;
                }
                batteryPercent.setText("Battery Level Remaining: " + level + " Thanks");
            }
        };


        EditText phoneNumber =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
        String phoneNumbers = phoneNumber.getText().toString();




        IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);

        String msg = String.valueOf(level);
        sendSMS("76335803", msg);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I add one record to PushRecord table that I created every time the user pushes and I fetch from that table if I want to show Pushes. Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to permanently store the notifications on the device, then your best bet is to create a database and store the notifications into that while in the BroadCast Reciever.

When you launch the app, you can then retrieve all notifications and display it in the ListView.

Comment: Okay..what if I want to show the notifications when there is internet connection only?